# No wifi on BCM43142 (but bluetooth works)

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, broadcom

I've always had some trouble with my wifi card. I was on Ubuntu 14.04 and sometimes I had no wifi and the option "enable wifi" didn't appear until I restarted my computer.

One day, it just stopped working, nothing to do.
I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10, still it doesn't work.

After I installed `bcmwl-kernel-source`, the bluetooth works but not the wifi, just like before.

I've tried so many solutions, but none of them worked for me:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

*(wlan0 doesn't exist)*

```
service network-manager restart
```

*(there's no problem with network-manager I guess)*

```
apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source 
apt-get install b43-fwcutter firware-b43-installer
```

*(I ended up reinstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` from the additional drivers tab)*

```
sudo modprobe wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

*(the process keeps running, but nothing happens)*

Checking secure mode in Bios ; already disabled

**brace yourselves**
I was so desperate that I thought that my ethernet card had some secret wireless powers XD so here's what I did

```
sudo lspci | grep -i ethernet
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)

sudo modprobe -rfv wl rt2800pci
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci
```

*should I undo it to fix this ? and how ?*
of course I ended up reinstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` as I said, from **Additional Drivers**.

of course, the wifi is on (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on my Dell inspiron 15)

Here are some outputs that could be useful:

`lspci`

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Net*
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

$ lspci -k | grep -i network -A 2
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Device 1128:0016
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

`lsusb`

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:649a Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`ifconfig`
*the interface wlan0 doesn't even exist*

```
$ sudo ifconfig
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:86:7a:61:2d:19  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:5723 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5836 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:3856720 (3.8 MB) Octets transmis:718950 (718.9 KB)


lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:4302 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1 
          Octets reçus:321187 (321.1 KB) Octets transmis:321187 (321.1 KB)
```

`iwconfig`

```
$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list`
*as I said, only Bluetooth is working*

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`ls -1 /etc/modprobe.d`

*the bcm43 is blacklisted, is that normal ? Or should I do something ?*

```
$ ls -1 /etc/modprobe.d/
alsa-base.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf
blacklist-bcm43.conf
blacklist.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf
blacklist-modem.conf
blacklist-oss.conf
blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist-watchdog.conf
dkms.conf
fbdev-blacklist.conf
intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
iwlwifi.conf
mlx4.conf
vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
```

`dmesg`

```
$ dmesg | grep wl
[   17.618389] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   17.620902] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   17.634296] wl driver 6.30.223.248 (r487574) failed with code 1
[   17.634405] Modules linked in: wl(POE+) snd_rawmidi snd_seq dell_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp mei_me snd_seq_device snd_timer kvm_intel cfg80211 kvm mei snd dell_laptop dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel joydev input_leds cryptd serio_raw shpchp lpc_ich soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse ahci drm r8169 libahci mii wmi video fjes
[   17.634930] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc07f3673>]  [<ffffffffc07f3673>] wl_cfg80211_detach+0xf3/0x100 [wl]
[   17.635549]  [<ffffffffc07eaf06>] ? wl_free_if.isra.15+0x26/0xa0 [wl]
[   17.635620]  [<ffffffffc07eb780>] wl_free+0x60/0x270 [wl]
[   17.635747]  [<ffffffffc07ebd3d>] wl_pci_probe+0x3ad/0x740 [wl]
[   17.642095]  [<ffffffffc03f2084>] wl_module_init+0x84/0x1000 [wl]
[   17.659643] RIP  [<ffffffffc07f3673>] wl_cfg80211_detach+0xf3/0x100 [wl]
```

Comment: What is the response when you do: `sudo modprobe wl`? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Now does wireless appear in `iwconfig`? If not, please show us: `dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: No it doesn't, for the output please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Your `dmesg` suggests a very unhappy hardware and driver combination. I suggest that you purge and reinstall the driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

With a working internet connection:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Note: This assumes that yours is a 64-bit installation; check: `arch`

Reboot and check again:

```
dmesg | grep wl
```

If you still see these alarming errors:

```
[   17.634296] wl driver 6.30.223.248 (r487574) failed with code 1
[   17.634405] Modules linked in: wl(POE+) snd_rawmidi snd_seq dell_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp mei_me snd_seq_device snd_timer kvm_intel cfg80211 kvm mei snd dell_laptop dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel joydev input_leds cryptd serio_raw shpchp lpc_ich soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse ahci drm r8169 libahci mii wmi video fjes
[   17.634930] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc07f3673>]  [<ffffffffc07f3673>] wl_cfg80211_detach+0xf3/0x100 [wl]
[   17.635549]  [<ffffffffc07eaf06>] ? wl_free_if.isra.15+0x26/0xa0 [wl]
[   17.635620]  [<ffffffffc07eb780>] wl_free+0x60/0x270 [wl]
[   17.635747]  [<ffffffffc07ebd3d>] wl_pci_probe+0x3ad/0x740 [wl]
[   17.642095]  [<ffffffffc03f2084>] wl_module_init+0x84/0x1000 [wl]
[   17.659643] RIP  [<ffffffffc07f3673>] wl_cfg80211_detach+0xf3/0x100 [wl]
```

Then, based on the fact that this failed on both 14.04 and 16.10, I suspect the hardware itself. Is the card seated firmly in its connector? Are the antenna wires connected firmly? Is the card electrically defective?

We see in your pastes that the kernel bug remains. I suggest that you blacklist the driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist wl"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Now, let's try an alternate driver:

```
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Any improvement? Any clues in the log?

```
dmesg | grep brcm
```

If you have tried unsuccessfully both the Broadcom proprietary driver *wl* as well as *brcmsmac*, then I suggest that you file a bug report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Finally, I'd invest in a USB wireless device until the bug is fixed. A search here and on ubuntuforums.org will reveal several.

Comment: dpkg is hanging on : dkms install completed, it did it a couple of times before succefully installing it the previous times so I will retry. For the hardware I just checked Dell diagnostic tool and it says in the cables part : wireless WAN : not installed. So I guess I should open it up.

Comment: Hi I'm back again, the hardware is okay I dont knom what to to do :(

Comment: Please reboot so that we have a clean slate and run: `dmesg > dmesg.txt` Find the file dmesg.txt in your home directory and paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Are you dual-booting? Does the card work as expected in Windows?

Comment: sorry for being late and thank you, here's the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/23863237/

Comment: and no I am not dual booting

Comment: In your dmesg, we see: "kernel BUG at include/net/cfg80211.h:3574!" I understood that the bug had been fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1303552 Please try the live DVD or USB for Ubuntu 16.10 and tell us if the error still appears in `dmesg`.

Comment: I tried booting on my live usb and installing bcmwl-kernel-source, the wifi still doesn't work. I'll retry it and give you the dmesg output. thanks. And sould I try installing an upstream kernel ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the kernel version as much as it is the bcmwl-kernel-source version. Judging by the Broadcom 43142 issues I see here and elsewhere, I suspect it is specific to that exact chipset.

Comment: this is the output (of the live usb) before I enabled the bcmwl-kernel-source from Additional pilotes http://paste.ubuntu.com/23863460/   , and this is the output after doing it http://paste.ubuntu.com/23863489/ , so I guess the bug is due to this driver but it doesnt disappear even after apt-get remove --purge bcwl-kernel-source , http://paste.ubuntu.com/23863523/

Comment: You appear to still be on 16.04. I recommend that you download and try the live session for 16.10 with its later 4.8 kernel and newer version of bcmwl-kernel-source.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I think I'll try dual-booting with windows to be sure. Like you said maybe the problem is with this specific chipset I've always had wifi problems. I'll try a live version of ubuntu 16.10 this evening and I will tell you the result.

Comment: So heres the result of dmesg on ubuntu 16.10 when I booted from a live usb, before installing the driver http://paste.ubuntu.com/23868114/ and after doing so http://paste.ubuntu.com/23868163/ , the kernel bug persists

Comment: Please see an edit above.

Comment: [   22.905479] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   22.905486] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found

Comment: thank you for evereything but it's not working :/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments. Sorry.

Comment: thank you so much, I will report the bug soon and I guess that I'll use my usb wireless device or dual-boot with windows in the meanwhile. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct driver installed, the `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

The problem is that it can't load because of Secure Boot option enabled in your BIOS. Disable it, and all should work.

You need to remove `blacklist wl` from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` if you did that already.

Comment: I've already mentioned in my post that the secure boot option in disabled and there's no such a line in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist. Thank you any way ^^

Comment: `[   17.620902] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel` shows that Secure Boot is on.

Comment: Maybe not if it is showing "in use".

Comment: that's weird, because in my boot options it's disabled and I can't even change that.